# How could I iterate through a 2D array, double each number, then print the updated array?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, methods, return

Like the question says, I am trying to take the array listed below and go through each number, double the number, and return the new number to the array, and when it's all done, call the method to print the new array. My initial thoughts were that maybe I could go through by row/column and get the number that way, multiply by 2, and then return it, but I'm being told something along the lines of int can't be converted to int[*,*]. I can not seem to figure out where to go from here.

```
int[,] array_2d = {{1, 2, 3},{ 4, 5, 6},{7, 8, 9}};

public static int[ , ] DoubleArray(int[ , ] array_2d){
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
  for (int col = 0; col < 3; col ++){
    int val = array_2d[row,col];
    return val * 2;
  }
 }
}
```

Also to clarify, The array is in the main method while this is a separate method needing to be called in the main with the array as the parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your DoubleArray function returns int[,], but inside of the loop you are trying to return an int, that is why you get the error int cannot be converted to int[,].  For your function you will want to create a new array to put those doubled values into, and return that new array.  eg. `newArr[x, y] = orgArr[x, y] * 2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your int-related error is that you state your return type as 'int[,]' and then in your return statement, you are attempting to return a value of type 'int'. In order to fix this, you need to return a 2d int array as specified by your return type. I would also recommend fetching the length of the array dynamically instead of hardcoding in the three. The below code should do the job.

```
public static int[,] DoubleArray(int[,] array_2d)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < array_2d.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < array_2d.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                int val = array_2d[row, col];
                array_2d[row, col] = val * 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return array_2d;
}
```

EDIT: As @hijinxbassist pointed out, this will modify the original array, if instead you would like to keep the value of the original, you can use the slightly altered function below.

```
public static int[,] DoubleArray(int[,] array_2d)
{
    int[,] newArray = (int[,])array_2d.Clone();

    for (int row = 0; row < newArray.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < newArray.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                int val = newArray[row, col];
                newArray[row, col] = val * 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can do something like that:

```
public static int[,] DoubleArray(int[,] array_2d)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            array_2d[row, col] = array_2d[row, col] * 2;
        }
    }

    return array_2d;
}

public static void PrintArray(int[,] array_2d)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{array_2d[row, col]} ");
        }
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] array_2d = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

    var doubledArray = DoubleArray(array_2d);

    PrintArray(doubledArray);
}
```

Comment: Be aware that you are modifying the contents of the original array.

Comment: Yep, he didn't say he couldn't do it, so I thought it was fine. But he can do it with the same code without modifying the original array, he just needs to declare another int[,] array and pass the result of multiplication to that array.

Comment: You are correct, it wasn't explicitly stated.  It is a good thing to note since some may think they are different variables when in fact that function doesn't need to return anything and will produce the same result.